# Method returns empty string in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I'm having trouble with this method. It returns empty string, what is wrong with this ?

I have this method:

```
public static string GetData(string Table1, string Column1, string WhereColumn, string WhereValue)
{
    Table1 = Methods.cleaninjection(Table1); // Some injection method that cleans the string

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString);

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + "@Column1" + " FROM " + Table1 + " WHERE " + "@WhereColumn" + " = " + "@WhereValue", connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Column1", Column1);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("WhereColumn", WhereColumn);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("WhereValue", WhereValue);

    try
    {
        if ((connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) || (connection.State == ConnectionState.Broken))
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
        string veri = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());
        return veri;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

When I run this, the command string looks like this:

> SELECT @Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE @WhereColumn = @WhereValue

It looks like correct but I couldn't find what is wrong.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try: `"SELECT " + Column1 + " FROM "...`

Comment: Tried but not worked, thanks.

Comment: Also, the `@WhereColumn`.  You can't use parameters as column or object names.

Comment: Now worked, thank you so much @Dan Guzman

Answer (score 2):

As commented, you cannot parameterize your column names and table names. Instead, do string concatenation:

```
"SELECT " + Column1 + " FROM " + Table1 + " WHERE " + WhereColumn + " =  @WhereValue";
```

Here is how your code should be:

```
public static string GetData(string Table1, string Column1, string WhereColumn, string WhereValue)
{
    Table1 = Methods.cleaninjection(Table1); // My injection method that cleans the string

    string sql = "SELECT " + Column1 + " FROM " + Table1 + " WHERE " + @WhereColumn + " =  @WhereValue";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@WhereValue", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = WhereValue;

            connection.Open();

            string veri = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());
            return veri;
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. Please do not use `AddWithValue`. Use `Parameters.Add()` instead. According to this [article:](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

> There is a problem with the AddWithValue() function: it has to infer
>   the database type for your query parameter. Here’s the thing:
>   sometimes it gets it wrong.

2. Wrap your object in `Using` to ensure proper cleanup of resources.
3. For additional security purposes, you can wrap your column name and table name in square brackets `[]`.

Comment: Okey thank you, but is this secure? And do you mean in your code like this? : WHERE + WhereColumn + " =  @WhereValue";

Comment: Also make sure to `cleanInjection` pretty much everything except `@WhereValue` which is the only actual parameter. And you want to be **really** sure that `cleanInjection` is up to the task. All in all I think the approach by @mrbengi is inherently flawed.

Comment: @mrbengi, thanks. If you're sure that both the table and column name are clean and safe, then, yes.

Comment: Thanks @Felix Pamittan but it still written in your method also

Comment: For additional security purposes, wrap your table names and columns name with `[]`.

Comment: But @Felix Pamittan are you sure that Add is secure? I knew as AddWithValue is more secure than the Add method.

Comment: I think in terms of security, both methods are the same. The difference is that `AddWithValue()` has to infer the DB type, which sometimes is wrong and cause performance issues.

Comment: Looking at the .net source code (http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlParameterCollection@cs/1/SqlParameterCollection@cs) there is very little difference between Add and AddWithValue.

Comment: The good thing with `Add` is you can specify the SQL datatype, unlike with `AddWithValue`. Say, you have a `VARCHAR` column, and `AddWithValue` sends your parameter as `NVARCHAR`. The DB will not convert the param into `VARCHAR` as it may lead to data loss. Instead, the column will be converted into `NVARCHAR`, which makes your `WHERE` clause non-SARGABLE.